# Goldbach's conjecture can't be proved to be undecidable?

Tags: prime-numbers, philosophy, natural-numbers, provability, goldbachs-conjecture

Conjectures concerning natural numbers which *could* be settled by a counterexample can, as far as I understand, not be proved to be undecidable without being proved not having a counterexample at the same time. Or?

Comment: Not sure what answer can be given here except "yes, that's right".

Comment: Well @Ben, is it right? There are people thinking that the Goldbach conjecture is unprovable. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27755/knuths-intuition-that-goldbach-might-be-unprovable

Comment: It can be unprovable without it being provable that it's unprovable.

Comment: If Goldbach's conjecture is proved to be undecidable in Peano arithmetic, there are models of arithmetic in which it is true, and models in which it is false. The existence of counterexamples is model-dependent, while provability of Goldbach's conjecture depends on the theory. But finding a counterexample in some model would prove that Goldbach's conjecture is either undecidable or false.

Comment: "The existence of counterexamples is model-dependent..." Not sure I get that, @zara. If it has a counterexample, then it's false, hence, decidable; so if it's undecidable, then it's true.

Comment: In the case it is undecidable, there exists a counterexample in some model, and there is a model in which there is no counterexample, that's what I was saying. Is there something wrong with that? @Gerry

Comment: I just don't see how there could be a counterexample in one model, and not in another. Can there be a number that's prime in one model, but not in another? Can there be two primes that add up to different numbers in two different models?

Comment: Since $\mathbb N$ is a minimal model a counterexample would be a counterexample in every model, but @aes is right of course, that a conjecture could be unprovable unprovable.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Any conditional counterexample would have to be a nonstandard integer. If it were a standard integer it would be a counterexample in all models.

Comment: Extensely discussed in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27755/knuths-intuition-that-goldbach-might-be-unprovable and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864149/could-it-be-that-goldbach-conjecture-is-undecidable.

Comment: Till a perfect 'proving' mechanism is created, there will always be new ways of proving statements to be found, and new ways to use the existing ones. We can not prove it unprovable till such a mechanism is found, and even that might not be implementable in finite time.

Answer (score 6):

If the Goldbach conjecture is undecidable (independent) of **PA**, then it is true for the standard model of arithmetic, i.e. the model $(\mathbb{N}, +, \times, 0, 1, <)$ with their normal interpretations.

Proof: Recall that $\mathbb{N}$ is the prime model of **PA**, (i.e. it embeds into **every** model $M$ such that $M\models$ **PA**). Further more, $\mathbb{N}$ is the initial segment of all models of **PA**. Assuming that $GC$ is independent of **PA**, we note that **PA** + $GC$ and **PA** + $\neg GC$ are consistent. Then, by Gödel's completeness theorem, there exists models $M_1$ and $M_2$ such that $M_1 \models$ **PA** + $GC$ and $M_2 \models$ **PA** + $\neg GC$. Suppose that $\mathbb{N} \models$ **PA** + $\neg GC$. Then, there exists some element $a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a$ cannot be written as the sum of two primes. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is the prime model of **PA**, we recall the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ embeds into all models of arithemtic. Therefore, if $\varphi(x)\equiv$ "$x$ cannot be written as the sum of two primes", and $\mathbb{N} \models \varphi(a)$.

By above, we showed there exist an $M_1$ such that $M_1 \models $ **PA** + $GC$. However, since $\mathbb{N}$ embeds into $M_1$, we note that $M_1 \models \varphi(\pi(a))$ (where $\pi$ is the embedding). However this implies that $M_1\models \neg GC$ which is a contradiction.

Thus, if $GC$ is independent of **PA**, then $\mathbb{N}\models GC$.

Comment: Are you sure the question isn't asking i Goldbach is independent of ℕ? Almost all references to PA are really to ℕ.

Comment: @Joshua: I hope they are referencing **PA** (or some non-specified theory). When you talk about decidability, it should be in relation to a theory and not a model.

Comment: @Joshua: Someone reference non-standard elements in the comments and so I think they are actually referring to a theory.