# Crude verification of Goldbach conjecture

Tags: number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

So the Goldbach conjecture says 'Every even integer greater than 2 can be written as sum of two primes'. Here is what I have roughly done to verify it, using probability. I don't say it is correct but I just want to show it.

Let *a* be an even integer greater than 2. The prime counting function gives number of primes *n* as *n* ~ *a*/ln *a*. Now, for every prime less than *a*, we generate odd numbers(except for 2)

*a*-p(*i*) where, p(*i*) is the *i*th prime below *a*.
Thus, we have approximately *n* odd numbers below *a*.

We have *n/a* = 1/ln*a* which gives the probability of prime number below *a*.

If we consider only the odd numbers below *a*, the probability becomes 2/ln*a*,
which means 2 out of ln*a* odd numbers below *a* are prime numbers.

But we have generated approximately(which just excludes case for 2 and is negligible for large numbers) *a*/ln*a* odd numbers.

So, from unitary method, 2/ln*a* out of 1 odd numbers below *a* are prime, 
which yields for our case,  $ 2 a/(lna)^2$ prime numbers out of *a*/ln*a* odd numbers generated.

And we can see that, 2 *a*/(ln*a*)^2 is obviously greater than 1 which even grows when *a* gets larger.

This shows that, among our generated odd numbers(*a*-p(*i*)) there is at least one prime number *q* giving,

*a*-p(*i*) = *q*

or, p(*i*) + *q* = *a*. where p(*i*) and *q* are primes, verifying Goldbach Conjecture.

Edit: I just wanted to know what is wrong with this approach(I knew there was). And I got my answer too. Thank you.

Comment: i could not understand the question you mentioned.

Comment: @BeWakePandey It isn't clear what your question is.  You give a crude heuristic which could be refined to a sharp heuristic, and though neither is proven.  What type of answer are you expecting that you'd accept??  As it stands, there isn't any question in your question.

Comment: Use anything but $e$, because $e$ is already universally defined.

Comment: @AaronThompson, I have corrected that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On average, you would expect around $2e/(\log e)^2$ primes.  But the $e/\log e$ numbers are a small proportion of the numbers below $e$, and it might happen, for one particular $e$, that none of them are prime.

Comment: but 2e/(log e)^2 is greater than 1 always, should not that mean by plain probability that there is at least 1 prime favouring GC?

Comment: No.  If you toss a coin three times, the number of heads will average to 3/2.  But sometimes you will get no heads.

Comment: yeah, that's true.

Comment: and by the way, has it been proven that GC can't be proven or disproven??

Comment: I don't know.  Here is an earlier question.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864149/could-it-be-that-goldbach-conjecture-is-undecidable

Comment: @BeWakePandey If it had been _proven_ that GC can't be disproven, that would amount to a proof that it's true, since any counterexample would become a trivial disproof.