Dubious proof of "if Goldbach’s conjecture is unprovable, it must be true"
Recently, I read a news article written by an "emeritus professor at UCD school of mathematics and statistics" that made the following curious claim about the Goldbach's conjecture: "But let us suppose the conjecture is unprovable. Then it must be true." Another document by the same author reproduces the claim. But is this actually true? The article contains a proof of this statement, but I do not understand it. Actually, the proof seems invalid to me. The proof from the article is:

Because, if it were false, there would be some finite even number that is not the sum of two primes. A finite search could confirm this, making the conjecture “provably false”! In other words, falsehood of the conjecture is incompatible with unprovability. This contradiction forces us to an ineluctable conclusion: if Goldbach’s conjecture is unprovable, it must be true!

So if $G$ is Goldbach's conjecture, and $P(G)$ means that Goldbach's conjecture is provable, then we could say the first two sentences from the quote prove that:
$$\lnot G \implies P(\lnot G) \tag{1}$$
The next sentence in the quotation is rather vague. (It is unclear what the word "unprovability" refers to.) It could mean both:
$$\lnot(\lnot G \land \lnot P(G)) \tag{2.1}$$
$$\lnot(\lnot G \land \lnot P(\lnot G)) \tag{2.2}$$
Proposition $(2.1)$ is clearly untrue: Goldbach's conjecture could be both false and unprovable. In contrast, $(2.2)$ could be derived from $(1)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\lnot G \implies P(\lnot G)             &&\text{assuming (1)} \\
G \lor P(\lnot G)                       &&\text{material implication} \\
\lnot(\lnot G \land \lnot P(\lnot G))   &&\text{De Morgan laws}
\end{align}
$$
Considering this, I assume that $(2.2)$ is the correct interpretation of the third sentence from the quote. The last sentence of the quote puzzles me; I do not see how "$\lnot P(G) \implies G$" follows from $(2.2)$. In fact, it seems the author is working with $(2.1)$. If we were to assume the (clearly false) proposition $(2.1)$, we could indeed prove the titular claim:
$$
\begin{align}
\lnot(\lnot G \land \lnot P(G))         &&\text{assuming (2.1)} \tag{I}\\
\lnot P(G)                              &&\text{assuming the antecedent} \tag{II} \\
\lnot(\lnot G \land \top)               &&\text{from (I) and (II)} \tag{III}\\
G                                       &&\text{simplifying (III)} \tag{IV}\\
\lnot P(G) \implies G                   &&\text{implication introduction from (II) into (IV)} \tag{V}
\end{align}
$$
It seems that the author himself got confused with the word "unprovability" in the third sentence of the quotation. But is it so? Is not there any mistake in my thoughts? The author is seemingly highly educated, while I lack any tertiary education in mathematics. (I apologize for any nonstandard notation or terminology in this question.)

I expect the professor was speaking informally, to a general audience.  It is true that a proof that goldbach was undecidable would prove that it was true (thereby contradicting the existence of such a proof) but of course it might in fact be undecidable though we remain unable to demonstrate that.   In any event, absent detailed context, I don't think there's a lot to say about the claim.

@lulu Why "a proof that goldbach was undecidable would prove that it was true"?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Goldbach's conjecture, if false, can be refuted and hence decided, so if it's undecidable it's true.

@AnneBauval  Maybe it's clearer to think of it as an instance of the Halting Problem.  It's easy to imagine a Turing Machine, or just a standard computer, being launched with a simple program to check each number in turn.  That program Halts if and only if Goldbach is false.  Therefore, a proof that it would never halt would prove the conjecture.

"a proof that it would never halt" would be stronger than a proof of undecidabiliy.   Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864149/could-it-be-that-goldbach-conjecture-is-undecidable/927030#927030

@AnneBauval  Well, perhaps my understanding is incorrect, but I don't see how my program could halt if the conjecture were provable in an extended axiom system.  The existence of such a system strikes me as incompatible with halting.  After all, my hypothetical program has to run equally well in this extended system.

The professor (and therefore you too!) seems to be using the word unprovable to mean undecidable, which to me is not the same thing at all $-$ a false statement is by definition unprovable (assuming the consistency of our axioms).

Welcome to MSE ! +1 for nicely written question with sufficiently great clarity ! We can see the Prof is wrong "Simply" by changing that Conjecture to something else like Parallel Postulate / Continuum Hypothesis / Riemann Hypothesis. We do not claim that these are all true too.

@Prem Falsity implies refutability for some conjectures, namely those for which a counterexample could be verified as such. Not all conjectures are like that, but Goldbach's definitely is.

That was why I said "Simply" in quotes ! More work will indeed be required , @J.G. , though I would change my list to include ODD Perfect Number Conjecture.

@TonyK Yes, the professor indeed seems to use unprovable to mean undecidable, but I did not know that when I was writing this question. I am, however, sure I did not use unprovable to mean undecidable, because this would make the propositions (2.1) and (2.2) equivalent, and it is clear I did not take them as equivalent.

The passage makes sense if we assume the author is using "unprovability" to refer to undecidability, i.e. the situation where $G$ is neither provably true nor provably false. Defining $U\equiv \lnot P(G)\land \lnot P(\lnot G)$, we can deduce $U\implies G$ from $\lnot G\implies P(\lnot G)$.

Thank you, this seems to be the most correct answer. It is easy to believe the author was using unprovable to mean undecidable, and the quoted proof is much more senseful if we read unprovable to mean undecidable.

As the author says it, the claim is very misleading. Something similar that is true is:

If the Goldbach conjecture is not refutable in Peano Arithmetic, then it is true.

Because suppose that the Goldbach conjecture is false. Then there is large even $n \in \mathbb N$ that cannot be written as the sum of two primes. Thus we can write the following true statement:

$\forall p < n,\ p$ is not a prime or $n-p$ is not a prime.

Here $n$ is of course represented by a numeral $n = SS\cdots S0$. The statement above can get expanded into one in $\mathsf{PA}$ that still uses only bounded quantifiers, so there is a proof of it by "brute force" and it can be written in $\mathsf{PA}$. Thus Goldbach is refutable.

Whether you use the term "undecidable" or "not refutable," the issue remains the same. If, staying strictly within any given system such as PA, you can prove irrefutability, you have a means to prove truth, contradicting the validity of the basic proof. Therefore, to prove irrefutability within PA (for example), you must work in a system that is more expansive than PA, such as by adopting additional axioms. In that case, you may be able to prove that the proposition is irrefutable within PA, but you have the problem of defending the extra axioms you invoke to make your proof.

My point is: if the Goldbach conjecture is false, then there is a refutation in PA. In order to show this, I'm using an informal argument, as in math. I'm not working in a specific "more expansive" system. Another similar way to understand this is that the negation of the Golbach conjecture is a $\Sigma_1$ sentence, and PA is complete for these.

@KeithBackman Also, I agree that the terms "undecidable" and "not refutable" both make the result clear. I do not agree with the author, though, when they use the term "provable" to mean "decidable".
